# Перетаскивание слайдеров мышкой

Tags: slider, javascript

Дали задание сделать на чистом JS (в основном плагинами jQuery пользовался).

Есть несколько section. Подскажите, как сделать перетаскивание мышкой по примеру (http://www.badassembly.com/ вверх-вниз).

```
<container>
    <section id="f1" name="About us">контент</section>
    <section id="f2" name="About us">контент</section>
    <section id="f3" name="About us">контент</section>
</container>
```

Понятно, что нужно сначала определить клик мыши:

```
addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

А вот как сделать перетаскивание мышкой и именно менять высоту контейнера - непонятно.

```
container.style.top = -500;
```

Нужно именно отследить при крике, не отпуская вертикальное положение мыши, что курсор сдвинулся вниз, например, на 10px, или вниз, или вверх.

Comment: Посмотри, как вот это устроенно:  http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/

Comment: Посмотрел пример, там нет перетаскивания слайдеров мышкой (в настройках тоже нет).

Comment: Ну да, я с телефона поглядел, скроллинг рукой работал, думал, там и под мышь есть кодина.

Когда-то использовал просто ее для одного проекта, остался очень доволен.

Answer (score 1):

Можно подключить это: http://www.idangero.us/swiper/demos/